# PHP/MYSQL IP Check/Logger

Tags: php, mysql, ip

Ok, ive got a minecraft server and im making a voting script for it.

I need a way to check the users ip in a mySQL.
If it doesn't exist it will put the ip in the database, and it will remove it after 24 hours in the database.

If anyone could help me do this, it would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of tutorials online on how to achieve this, thus I wont give you the code. Just a few hints to get you started.

In PHP, you can get the user's ip address from the `$_SERVER` superglobal

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

To check if it exists in your table

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE `ip` = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($ip));
```

If it does not exist, store it using the `INSERT` command along with a timestamp.

As for removing after 24 hours, you can set up a cron job that runs through the table every hour or so and removes all entries that have expired. However, it would be easier to not remove the entries. Instead, when a user votes, just check the timestamp of his last vote. If 24 hours have passed since the last vote, just update the timestamp.

Basically, the workflow would be:

```
1. Get users's IP address.
2. Does this IP exist in table? 
  2a. If no, let user vote, and enter his ip in the table along with the current time in the timestamp column
  2b. If yes, get the timestamp of his last vote. Has it been 24 hours since his last vote?
    2b.a. If yes, let user vote and update timestamp column with current time.
    2b.b. If no, do not let user vote / reject his vote. Leave timestamp column unchanged.
```

Comment: Why do you escape the IP address?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this, but it might be possible that the client can enter a custom value for `REMOTE_ADDR` just like they can for `user agent` if they make the request from outside the browser (such as telnet). Since I wasn't sure, I figured its safer to just escape it

Comment: Hm...... im very confused here, im quite new to php, could you help me out a bit more

Comment: Any more help would require me writing the code out for you. What you're attempting is fairly trivial, and no more than 10-20 lines of code. I recommend you go over some PHP tutorials online

Comment: @xbonez  you can not manipulate remotely with $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], as it is populated by the server based on the TCP tunnel data.

Comment: @Cheery it is just a good habit. In fact, a developer should not think of such matters at all. There is a rule - it must be followed. Quoted strings have to be escaped. That's all. No need to troll good practices.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do the following

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
// Run cleanup for given IP
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table 
             WHERE `ip`='$ip' AND `timestamp` > NOW() - 24*3600");  
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) 
// there is no record within the last 24h, let insert a new one
{  
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO table SET `ip`='$ip', `timestamp` = NOW()");  
 echo "Thank you for your vote!";
}
else echo "You may vote only once in 24 hours";
// run total cleanup query from time to time
if (rand(1,5)<2) mysql_query("DELETE FROM table 
                             WHERE `timestamp` < NOW() - 24*3600");
```

ps: If you have different votings, each of them should have different unique ID. and the MySQL table, which had before two columns `ip` and `timestamp`, should have one more column `voteid`, for example. In that case the code above will change to

```
// voteid should be somehow set to the id of the voting. 
// for example by GET request
$voteid = intval($_GET['voteid']);
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
// Run cleanup for given IP
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table 
   WHERE `ip`='$ip' AND `voteid`='$voteid` AND `timestamp` > NOW() - 24*3600");  
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) 
// there is no record within the last 24h, let insert a new one
{  
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO table SET `ip`='$ip', 
                `voteid`='$voteid', `timestamp` = NOW()");  
   echo "Thank you for your vote!";
}
  else echo "You may vote only once in 24 hours";
  // run total cleanup query from time to time
 if (rand(1,5)<2) mysql_query("DELETE FROM table 
                                 WHERE `timestamp` < NOW() - 24*3600");
```

Comment: @user1177550  what do you mean by the `database info`? connection to the MySQL server or what?

Comment: Also, there are multiple vote sites where they vote. How could i just make this effect one vote site. So they can vote every 24 hours on each vote site, if you get what i mean?

Comment: I mean the connection to the mySQL

Comment: @user1177550     you have to state all requirements in your question. If you need a few options then there should be one more column in the table, with id of the site. And all queries should include this id in condition. Connection should be placed anywhere BEFORE that code as shown here http://www.php.net/mysql_select_db

Comment: @user1177550     Check for updates in the code. Made some typos there before and fixed them. I have to sleep a couple of hours :)